# Cannot get the black canvas to display on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a black canvas for the pong game that I am making, but I cannot get it to draw on the screen

I have checked the console and have no errors

```js
// select the canvas that we have made in our html file
const cvs = document.getElementById("pong");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

// draw our rectangle function 

function drawRect(x, y, w, h, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}

drawRect(0, 0, cvs.wdith, cvs.height, "BLACK");
```

```html
<canvas id="pong" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: `width !== wdith`

Comment: I have changed that still nothing being displayed on the screen

Comment: Please edit the code in your question - then make it a snippet. If you don't know how ask me to do it for you.

Comment: Are you sure you changed `wdith` to `width`? Because the code you've provided does work if you change only that.

Comment: works thank you so much! my fault for not reading my code correclty